# How to convert the Differential pressure in Pa to flow rate?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, sensors, airflow, embedded-systems

I am using SDP32 sensor and got the differential pressure value of the air. I want to convert this value to flow rate. What is the equation for that?

Comment: What type of conduit is it attached to ?

Comment: Is that through a calibrated orifice?

Comment: come back, diagram out your system, and describe what your sensor is attached to.

Comment: If you have enough pressure sensors, you can measure dynamic pressures at different points, giving you an idea of the distribution of flow velocities.  If you have static pressures as well as temperatures a good way to obtain density and other fluid properties, and an idea of your geometry, getting flow rates is not unheard of.  You need more data than a single differential pressure, which is really just a good way to measure (total pressure - static pressure)=dynamic pressure.

Answer (score 0):

In general case pressure difference is described by [Hagen–Poiseuille equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation). In the case of pipe it can be described by more practical [Darcy–Weisbach equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation).
Simplest way, as i think, is to graduate your sensor by industrial flow meter.